# dealing with dups in end of the array

Tags: c

This is the task I have got:
I need to write a function (not recursive) which has two parameters.

1. An array of integers.
2. An integer representing the size of the array.

The function will move the duplicates to an end of the array.

And will give the size of the different digits.

Example:

> 5 , 2 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 2, n = 7
> we will get back 5 , 2 , 4 , 6 , 7 , 5 , 2  and 5

1. We must keep the original sort as it is (which means like in example 5 must)
2. It does not matter how we sort the duplicates ones but just keep the sort for the original array as it is)
3. The function has to print the number of different digits (like in example 5)
4. The the input range of numbers in array [-n,n]
5. I can only use 1 additional array for help.
6. It has to be *O(n)*

I tried it so many times and feel like am missing something. Would appreciate any advice/suggestions.

```c
int moveDup(int* arr, int n)
{
    int* C = (int*)calloc(n * 2 + 1, sizeof(int));
    assert(C);
    /*int* count = C + n;*/
    int *D = arr[0];
    int value = 0, count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        value = arr[i];
        if (C[value + n] == 0)
        {
            *D = arr[i];
            D++;
            count++;
        }
        C[value + n] = C[value + n] + 1;
    }
    while (1 < C[value + n])
    {
        *D = i;
        D++;
        C[value + n]--;
    }
    free(C);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You never asked a question. What difficulty are you facing? Does the above code not work?

Comment: @Haris i am kinda lost there, dont even know what to ask , just need some explanation on how to do it

Comment: Hint: Use the one allowed auxiliary array to count how many times each value has been seen.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's what i tried and it didnt work well...

Comment: If that is what you tried, then show it. The code currently in the question does not count how many times each value has been seen. It only records whether a value has been seen or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Set `int *destination = arr;`. Iterate through the array. For each element, increment the count of the number of times it has been seen. If it has been seen only once so far, copy to `*destination` and increment `destination`. After the loop, all the unique values will be in the front of the array. Then you have to figure out the number of unique elements and you have to fill in the back of the array. You can figure out the number of unique elements from the value of `destination`. Think about how you can use `destination` to know the number of unique elements.

Comment: And think about how you can use `counts` to fill in the back of the array.

Comment: but i cant use 2 more arrays like *memory and *destination, only 1 additional array can be used

Comment: @secret1: There is only one additional array, in the space allocated for `memory`. `count` is a pointer into it, and `destination` is a pointer into `arr`. `counter` and `pointer` could be replaced by integer indices if necessary.

Comment: i am a little bit confused , count is a pointer to end of the array?
or what value *count get.

Comment: @secret1: `int *memory = calloc(2*n+1, sizeof *memory);` allocates memory for 2n+1 elements. `int *count = memory + n;` sets `count` to point n elements into that. Do the math. If `count` points `n` elements beyond `memory`, how many of the 2n+1 elements are before `count`? How many of the 2n+1 elements are after `count`?

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm will produce the required results in O(*n*) [arithmetic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity#Others):

- Input is an array *A* with *n* elements indexed from *A*<sub>0</sub> to *A*<sub>*n*−1</sub> inclusive. For each *A*<sub>*i*</sub>, −*n* ≤ *A*<sub>*i*</sub> ≤ *n*.
- Create an array *C* that can be indexed from *C*<sub>−*n*</sub> to *C*<sub>+*n*</sub>, inclusive. Initialize *C* to all zeros.
- Define a pointer *D*. Initialize *D* to point to *A*<sub>0</sub>.
- For 0 ≤ *i* < *n*:

  - If *C*<sub>*A*<sub>*i*</sub></sub>=0, copy *A*<sub>*i*</sub> to where *D* points and advance *D* one element.
  - Increment *C*<sub>*A*<sub>*i*</sub></sub>.
- Set *r* to the number of elements *D* has been advanced from *A*<sub>0</sub>.
- For −*n* ≤ *i* ≤ +*n*:

  - While 1 < *C*<sub>*A*<sub>*i*</sub></sub>:

    - Copy *i* to where *D* points and advance *D* one element.
    - Decrement *C*<sub>*A*<sub>*i*</sub></sub>.
- Release *C*.
- Return *r*. *A* contains the required values.

A sample implementation is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define NumberOf(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof *(a))


int moveDuplicates(int Array[], int n)
{
    int *memory = calloc(2*n+1, sizeof *Array);
    if (!memory)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int *count = memory + n;

    int *destination = Array;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        //  Count each element.  If it is unique, move it to the front.
        if (!count[Array[i]]++)
            *destination++ = Array[i];

    //  Record how many unique elements were found.
    int result = destination - Array;

    //  Append duplicates to back.
    for (int i = -n; i <= n; ++i)
        while (0 < --count[i])
            *destination++ = i;

    free(memory);
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    int Array[] = { 5, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2 };
    printf("There are %d different numbers.\n",
        moveDuplicates(Array, NumberOf(Array)));
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOf(Array); ++i)
        printf(" %d", Array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,
I got 2 questions, first of all when you mean copy you mean swap between them?
and the second one is i am confused why the while loop is needed.

Comment: @secret1: No, “copy” means copy. Work through the algorithm on paper with simple examples, like “3 3 1” or “3 3 1 3 2”.

Comment: just to make sure in the last while loop you mean *D = i and then D++?

Comment: @secret1: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: i dont understand the point of making *d = i if i is the index of arr , and assign the index of arr[1] = 1 is making any logic?

Comment: Enable warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. Also, there is a “for” loop in the algorithm that is not in your code.

Comment: for in while loop  is On^2 complexity no? and why is that for needed ?

Comment: @secret1: Work through the algorithm on paper with simple examples, so you understand it. Once you understand it, figure out the greatest number of times the code inside “while” inside the “for” can be executed.

Comment: N*2+1?
but i still can't understand it.
can you maybe like fix my code so i could finally understand it...

Comment: managed to do it by myself.
took about a few days of sitting but done

Answer (score 1):

**here is the right answer, figured it out by myself.**

```
int moveDup(int* arr, int n)
{
    int* seen_before = (int*)calloc(n * 2 + 1, sizeof(int));
    assert(seen_before);
    int val = 0, count = 0, flag = 1;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        val = arr[i];
        if (seen_before[arr[i] + n] == 0)
        {
            seen_before[arr[i] + n]++;
            count++;
            continue;

        }
        else if (flag)
        {
            j = i + 1;
            flag = 0;
        }
        while (j < n)
        {
            if (seen_before[arr[j] + n] == 0)
            {
                count++;
                seen_before[arr[j] + n]++;
                swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
                j++;
                if (j == n)
                {
                    free(seen_before);
                    return count;
                }
                break;
            }
            /*break;*/
            j++;
            if (j == n)
            {
                free(seen_before);
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**second right answer**

```
    int* mem = (int*)calloc(2 * n + 1, sizeof * arr);
    assert(mem);
    int* count = mem + n;
    int* dest = arr;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (count[arr[i]]++ == 0)
        {
            *dest = arr[i];
            *dest++;
        }
    }
    res = dest - arr;
    for (i = -n; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        while (0 < --count[i])
        {
            *dest++ = i;
        }
    }

    free(mem);
    return res;
```

Comment: Explain what you've changed to make it better.