# checking for duplications in sorted array

Tags: c

I am doing some homework and i stuck in a section
where i need to move all the duplicates in a sorted array to the end of the array.
I know how to do it with 1 additional array but without additional array i dont know(a bit confusing pointers)

i tried this idea: (but its not working and no idea why)

```
int main()
{
    int newArr[12] =  {};
    int n = 12;
    int first = 0;
    int last = n - 1;
    int* D = arr + 1;
    int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        j = i + 1;

        while (j < n)
        {
            if (newArr[i] != *D)
            {
                D++;
            }
            if (newArr[i] == *D)
            {
                swap(&newArr[i], &newArr[last]);
                j++;
                last--;
            }
            j++;
        }
        
            
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", newArr[i]);
    }
}
```

**the working 2 array version:**

```
int moveDuplicatesV1(int* arr, int n)
{
    int* seen_before = (int*)calloc(n * 2 + 1, sizeof(int));
    assert(seen_before);
    int val = 0, count = 0, flag = 1;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        val = arr[i];
        if (seen_before[arr[i] + n] == 0)
        {
            seen_before[arr[i] + n]++;
            count++;
            continue;

        }
        else if (flag)
        {
            j = i + 1;
            flag = 0;
        }
        while (j < n)
        {
            if (seen_before[arr[j] + n] == 0)
            {
                count++;
                seen_before[arr[j] + n]++;
                swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
                j++;
                if (j == n)
                {
                    free(seen_before);
                    return count;
                }
                break;
            }
            /*break;*/
            j++;
            if (j == n)
            {
                free(seen_before);
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered ending the "search" when `i == last` (or something like that)... Don't go wandering into the pool of values that have been exiled to the end of the array...

Comment: It will be a lot quicker if you just tell us the desired and actual result; _"its not working"_ is insufficient and would require analysts or execution.  Have you used a debugger to investigate this?  Your course should ideally teach debug techniques.

Comment: well i do know how to use the debugger
but i cant understand the logic behind searching for duplicates (what i actullay have to do / "search") so its kinda pointless to use a debugger without purpose of checking myself.

Comment: That would suggest that it is not your code?  Besides, by stepping in the debugger and watching the variable state, you can study the code behaviour, so your argument that is "pointless" makes no sense, and suggests that you do not really understand debugging as much as you think.  Despite its name, a debugger is not only for debugging

Comment: Surely "swapping" will dis-order the array, you might consider a memmove to "close the gap" then place the duplicate in the vacated space at the end.

Comment: no i actually wrote it , i wrote something similar but with an additional array so i tried to write the same with pointers.
i understand your point about debugging and i will give it a try.
i did learn about debugging and i know its not only for debugging but i usually had no need to use it until now.

Comment: and thanks for hint about swapping that's pretty much what i needed i guess

Comment: Perhaps you should post the working two-array version that you "know" how to do.  I cannot reconcile that with your comment that it is the "search for duplicates" you do not understand - that would be the same in both versions, and is not what you are asking about in your question.

Comment: i have posted the 2 array version ( which is not sorted )

Comment: Why must you use pointers?  If that is confusing you, use array indexing.

Comment: Both versions seem overcomplicated to me to be honest.

Comment: i thought i must use here pointers..
and i kinda should practice pointers i guess...

Comment: what am i missing out then?

Comment: Are you [double posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74955091/c-remove-duplicates-from-an-array-to-the-end-of-the-array)? The answer there will work here, since sortedness does not matter for the O(n) answer.

Comment: @secret1 :  I suggest you use pointers when you _need_ to.  "practising" with contrived examples when it is probably inappropriate or unnecessary will perhaps teach you nothing useful.  I have posted an answer, I can assure you that I did not arrive at the solution without using a debugger - and I have been doing this for over 30 years.  Think of it as a code testing, comprehension and development aid rather than a "debugger".   In the debugger I could see the memory move, check the indexes and comparisons and evaluate the expressions to see they were yielding the expected value.

Comment: @Dúthomhas :  That looks like his two-array solution - this is about performing the transform "in place", so not a duplicate _question_ (or answer for that matter).

Comment: @secret1  By way of advice, I am willing to bet that you will get additional marks if you include comments.  It will also help debugging - by writing comments you have to "_explain it to yourself_" - that often helps.  No comments like `// increment j` though - write what the code is for and how it works.  See my answer for example.  Also the comments explain the code to your tutor - they may not necessarily be that proficient, or you may use some idiom with which they are unfamiliar - help them give you marks rather then treating them with contempt or assuming they will understand your code.

Answer (score 3):

Consider your array:

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

It sounds like you're trying to get to:

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 9 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 7 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If we start at index 0 and compare to index 1, they are not the same, so we move on to comparing index 1 and index 2.

*They are the same.* So we increment a `dupes_found` variable from `0` to `1`. We save `arr[i]` and move the rest of the array forward 1 position, then copy what was in `arr[i]` into the last spot in the array.

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 9 | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Because we've moved the array, we don't move forward. We now compare indices 1 and 2 again. They are still the same, so we repeat, having again incremented `dupes_found`.

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 9 | 2 | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

When we're at the length of the array minus the `dupes_found`, the job is complete.

An implementation might look something like:

```
void relocate_duplicates_to_end(int *arr, size_t n) {
    size_t dupes_found = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1 - dupes_found;) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
            dupes_found++;
            int temp = arr[i];
            memmove(&arr[i], &arr[i+1], sizeof(int) * (n - i - 1));
            arr[n - 1] = temp;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between memmove and swap?

Comment: [Documentation for `memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove)

Answer (score 1):

@Chris drew some pretty pictures for you and I wrote the matching  implementation.  Starting at position 1 instead of 0 is a minor refactoring.  My implementation, as noted below, return a pointer to the first duplicate value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 [0; i[: unique values
 [i; n - d[: possible duplicates (yet to be processed)
 [n-d; n[: duplicates

 return pointer to first duplicate value.  Note this is
 1 past the end of a if there are no duplicates.  This is
 ok just don't dereference it before checking.
*/
int *partition(size_t n, int a[n]) {
    size_t d = 0;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < n-d;) {
        if(a[i-1] == a[i]) {
            int tmp = a[i];
            memmove(a+i, a+i+1, (n-i-1) * sizeof(*a));
            a[n-1] = tmp;
            d++;
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return a + n - d;
}

void print_a(const char *prefix, size_t n, const int a[n]) {
    printf("%s", prefix);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i + 1 < n ? ", " : "");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {1,2,2,2,3,3,5,6,7,7,9,9};
    size_t n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
    int *p = partition(n, a);
    print_a("unique   : ", p - a, a);
    print_a("duplicate: ", n - (p - a), p);
}
```

and the output is:

```
unique   : 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9
duplicate: 2, 2, 3, 7, 9
```

You could elect to move `n - d - i - 2` elements
and insert the new duplicate element at a[d] (instead of a[n-1]).  This will reverse sort the duplicate partition.  If you care then reverse the duplication partition before you return.  It will probably be a little faster.

Another optimization would to move a run of (r - 1) duplicate values by copying the first into `tmp` as above, create a (r - 1) hole with `memmove()` then write (r-1) copies of `tmp` in that hole (either at `a[d-r-1]` or `a[n-r-1]`).

Comment: Chris also included an implementation.  Is this somehow different/better?

Comment: @Clifford He added the implementation after I wrote my answer.  Upvote the answers that were helpful and it's up to you to accept the best answer.

Comment: Sorry - I was looking at the edit time, not your original post time.  That makes sense.  I am not the OP, I cannot accept anything.  Your solution does use pointer arithmetic which the OP seems keen to use rather than array indexing  (against my advice, but that's his choice), so in that sense it is both different and possibly what the OP would want.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun (that's unlikely what OP was required to do), the following is an algorithm that doesn't require extra memory to move all the duplicates to the end of the array.

It doesn't use `memmove`, but a single optional swap at every step. That means that it isn't stable and requires the duplicates to be sorted as a final step.

I'd call it a rolling bubble, for lack of a better analogy:

```
// It will use qsort, so it needs a comparator function
int cmp_int(void const *a, void const *b)
{
  int x = *(int const *)a;
  int y = *(int const *)b;
  return (y < x) - (x < y);
}

void i_swap(int *a, int *b)
{
  int tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

// The function returns the index of the first duplicate
size_t unique_partition(size_t n, int *arr)
{
  // In general, the passed array could be unsorted.
  qsort(arr, n, sizeof *arr, cmp_int);

  // Find the first duplicate.
  size_t i = 1;
  while ( i < n  &&  arr[i] != arr[i - 1] )
  {
    ++i;
  }
  if ( i == n )
  {
    return n;
  }
  
  // Now it has to move around the duplicates. 
  size_t n_dupes = 1;
  while ( ++i < n )
  {
    // If it's a duplicate of the last unique value, just add it to the "bubble".
    if ( arr[i] == arr[i - n_dupes - 1] )
    {
      ++n_dupes;
    }
    // Otherwise swap it with the first duplicate. It becomes the new last unique.
    else
    {
      i_swap(arr + i, arr + i - n_dupes);
    }
  }

  // As mentioned, the duplicates are shuffled now.
  qsort(arr + n - n_dupes, n_dupes, sizeof *arr, cmp_int);

  return n - n_dupes;
}
```